# Looking for a PHP mailing list App (not for newsletters)

Tags: php, email, mailing-list, mailman

I am not sure if I'm calling this correctly by the right name, what I would like to find (if it exists) is a group mailing list app (like mailman) but in php.

Here is what I expect it to do:

Allow for users to email `mailinglist@domain.com`
with subject like `TEAM123 - Deadline is 11/30/2011` (or maybe just team123@domain.com)
and this application would CHECK the mailbox

It would check the mailbox, and forward that message to all users in `TEAM123`.  So the email thread would then be created.

Users then would be notified in `TEAM123`, and by replying, would update the mail thread (the emails would then again go out to everyone).  Maybe at this point the app would update a running conversation on the site (store it in DB? etc).

I think I'm calling the process properly 'mailing list service' etc..

Anyone aware of anything like this in PHP?  I would use this for a sports league, players would just have to update via email and the whole team would be updated.

Thanks! Appreciate any ideas on this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've actually written some internal software that does this. I believe the term you're looking for is 'discussion list' (as opposed to 'announcement list'). The reason I ended up writing it on my own is because - to my knowledge - a well known software package doesn't exist.

**Announcement list - plenty. Discussion lists - no so much.**

As an aside, the reason there's not much out there may be because a forum is a much better tool to use. The well known discussion list software has been around for *years*, developed when people had e-mail addresses, but not always web access.

I'll disagree with Rudism, in that a cron job or a special SMTP server is **not** needed. Postfix can be rather easily configured to send incoming e-mails to a PHP script, which then processes the mail.

Libraries like [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html), [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) make *sending* email easy. In my experience the hardest part is processing incoming e-mails. However, the popular e-mail libraries have made some progress in that direction (from what I've seen).

My recommendation is use a discussion list service, or a forum (maybe with e-mail notification). If you are set on running your own server, you could write a bare-bones script pretty easily.

Comment: I explored the option for forums (I'm no stranger), and we do use an annouce (newsletter) approach. BUT I find most team members (this is a non IT sports team were talking here) mainly stick to email.  And I have seen this type of mailman approach function VERY well in another setting, as everyone would reply.

Comment: I understand - the reason I'm still running *one* discussion list is because it just works for those who use it. If you're just going to run a single list, the code would be even simpler. Just check that the sending address is a member, add the group addresses, then resend the mail. Most mail libraries let you create a new mail object from an actual e-mail, then edit it and resend. So your process script can be pretty simple.

Comment: To be fair, I would consider postfix configured to send incoming mails to a php script to be specialized :)

Comment: @rudism Yeah, I doubt it's something you'll find on many shared hosts, but it's not really that hard to edit the alias file.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.phplist.com/

---

Edit:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-mailman/

Comment: How so? From their site I see: 
`phplist is a one-way email announcement delivery system. It is great for newsletters, publicity lists, notifications, and many other uses. (It is different from group mailing list systems like mailman.)`

Comment: Yeah, this is not what @jakub is looking for, it is expressly the opposite.

Comment: My understanding of the php-mailman is that it's only an *interface* to mailman's configuration.

Answer (score -3):

PHP would not be an ideal platform for such an application, since it would require either a specialized SMTP server to accept the incoming emails, or some kind of server-side cron job to continually check a mailbox and take action. While these could theoretically be done in PHP, it's more suited to web development and being executed by a web server.

Comment: See I'm aware of apps like `mailman` but I would love to see this in a php flavor.  Hence why I asked, I don't think a cron would be bad...

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, using a php script as the endpoint of an address is not that hard. Something you may not be able to do on shared hosting, but I've done it multiple times. However, a cron job checking an inbox wouldn't be bad (it just has a different set of issues to consider).